# Mesh Dilation or Expansion for 3D printing Project

Tags: mesh

I'm totally new to Blender and this forum & I'm looking for a tool to help me with my 3D printing project.

I am working with a mesh for an object that you can imagine to be be a coil or a spring: it is a twisted filament with a good bit of geometry in it (it is not a sculpture, for example).

The filament itself is rather thin, which makes it difficult to 3D print so ideally I could expand the mesh to make the filament thicker. I tried exploring this using MeshMixer with not so great results, particularly because I cannot perform mesh dilation in a single operation to the whole mesh, and instead have to work my way manually through the mesh which creates artefacts that greatly distort the initial geometry.

Do you think that Blender can be a solution for this problem? Could you please give me some pointers on how to go about to do this?

Many thanks for the help.

Best,
R.

Comment: Difficult to be sure of the solution without seeing the model.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the mesh a displace modifier with default settings will inflate or deflate the mesh along its normals. Tweak the strength to vary the effect.

[image]

Concave mesh will self-intersect if the strength is too high or too low so keep that in mind.

[image]